# How can I kill a ros2 node with rclpy?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a launch file that launches 3 ROS2 nodes and the nodes are wrote using rclpy. Now,  I'm planning to write a service call that will kill 2 of those nodes. After doing some research, I found something called "lifecycle Node", but as far as I know "lifecycle" still only supports C++ (according to the outlook https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/foxy/lifecycle/README.rst).

I did found a hacky way (https://answers.ros.org/question/378126/ros2-launch-lifecycle-callback-component/) but I'm not confident with that approach.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any other way I can kill the ROS2 node other than using pressing ctrl+c and lifecycle node?
2. How can I do the killing of a node properly in rclpy?

I'm using OS=Linux 20.04 LTS | ROS_DISTRO=Foxy | ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386657/how-can-i-kill-a-ros2-node-with-rclpy?/) by [FlyingChickenGang](https://answers.ros.org/users/84859/flyingchickengang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FA](https://answers.ros.org/users/155366/fa/) on 2023-06-22**:
Please specify how to use os to find the node's names and PID numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct, LifeCycle Nodes are only cpp and would be a nicer implementation. The node in this case would never be completely killed but you can easily restart a node with decent tools.

If you just want to kill the node through a service call, I would recommend to do it with the normal python way: `exit()`. Than your node should be gracefully exited which has the same effect than what you might desire.

Restarting would then be a part that might be a little bit harder. But probably you could hack your way around with using parts of a launch file in a normal python script. But I would not straight forward recommend that, as I do not know the possible side effects of that.

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [flo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55147/flo/) with karma: 111 on 2021-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FlyingChickenGang](https://answers.ros.org/users/84859/flyingchickengang/) on 2021-09-22**:
Thanks for the comment and suggestion. I have also tried another method, which is using python `os` to find out all the nodes' name and their PID numbers. Then, killing those by using `os.kill((PID), signal.SIGTERM)`.

**Comment by [flo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55147/flo/) on 2021-09-23**:
please consider adding this comment as own answer and tick it as the correct one. Or use mine to show others that this problem can be solved.. :)